# Unhandled by MetaTagHandler for type

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

We have a composite with a editableValueHolder, and I am passing a converter and validator in.
I created this little example because I can see that a value of 100.1 is accepted because the converter is called first and is integer only.

```
<xyz:InputTextComposite compId = "accountNumber" 
    property="#{myBean.accountNumber}" 
        <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" for="inputTextContents"/>
    <f:validateDoubleRange maximum="100" minimum="10" for="inputTextContents" />
</xyz:InputTextComposite>
```

However, I am seeing  this in the log :-

```
Feb 19, 2013 12:11:58 PM org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.MetaRulesetImpl finish
SEVERE: /linked/OLT/y.xhtml at line 16 and column 68 for="inputTextContents" Unhandled by MetaTagHandler for type javax.faces.convert.NumberConverter
```

Although it works, I don't feel I can deliver a system like this :-(